# .replace() no longer working for me

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I've been using the following function for some time with great success, but just recently it stopped working. I've not changed anything; same browser, server, same jquery library, everything's the same so I'm lost on what's wrong. The following function takes a long string and converts it to an object:

```
$(function()
{   
    var _sid    = getUrlVar('AICC_SID');
    var _url    = getUrlVar('AICC_URL');
    $.get(_url,{command:"GetParam",version:"2.2",session_id:_sid},function(response)
    {
        var _obj = toJSON(response);
        console.log(_obj);
    });
});

function toJSON(str) 
{
    var obj = {};
    str.replace(/([^=]+)=(.*)\n/g, function (_, name, value)
    {
        console.log('name : ' + name);
        console.log('value : ' + value);
        obj[name] = $.trim(value);
    });
    return obj;
}
```

Here's the string that get's converted:

```
ERROR=0
ERROR_TEXT=Successful
VERSION=2.2
AICC_DATA=[CORE]
STUDENT_ID=0425655
STUDENT_NAME=Doe, John B
SCORE=
TIME=00:00:00
CREDIT=C
LESSON_LOCATION=1_5
LESSON_STATUS=NULL
[Core_Lesson]
[Objectives_Status]
```

The problem is the `.replace()` appears to not be running. The `toJSON()` function converts the string to an object, but it always returns and empty object. Hopefully that clears up what's wrong.

Comment: What errors are you seeing?

Comment: [Attach a debugger and test it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code)

Comment: The last two lines don't match your regex, nor do they meet your requirements for generating key/value pairs on your object

Comment: No errors are being thrown, the .replace() is not even running.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I imagine it's because you didn't describe what was actually wrong. You just said it wasn't working. Questions must: "Include *attempted solutions*, *why they didn't work*, and *the expected results*"

Comment: Are you sure the `$.get` is executing the success handler? Per http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/: "If a request with jQuery.get() returns an error code, it will fail silently unless the script has also called the global .ajaxError() method."

Comment: By "`.replace()` appears not to be running" you mean that you don't see the console.log messages in the console either?

Comment: @Juhana that is correct. The `console.log()` in the `$.get()` works fine, but the `console.log()` in the replace never fires.

Comment: ...that means `toJSON()` isn't being called, not that the regex isn't working.

Comment: I thought `toJSON()` wasn't firing, but I put an `alert()` to see and the `alert()` fired. So I'm positive `toJSON()` is firing.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `\n` from your RegEx.

So it looks like this:

`str.replace(/([^=]+)=(.*)/g, ...`

I'm guessing it's a problem related to line breaks.

**UPDATE**

Try updating `toJSON()` with this:

```
function toJSON(str) {
        var obj = {};
        str.replace(/([^=]+)=(.*)/g, function (_, name, value) {
            name = name.replace(/\n/g, '');

            console.log('name : ' + name);
            console.log('value : ' + value);
            obj[name] = $.trim(value);
        });
        return obj;
    }
```

Comment: your suggestion is working, but the string I'm converting appears to have `/n` after each line, so in the `console.log()` it's showing a new line.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Let me know if you have any success.

Comment: Just tried it and it doesn't appear to do anything to the`/n`.